# Running Applet on ServerSide after Successful Upload

Tags: java, applet, server-side, post-processing

I am making an Uploader Which uploads Audio File
Now i want following things to be done:

- Once File is Uploaded to Server an Applet should start on ServerSide
- Name & other details of Uploaded content should be passed to Applet
- Applet will process somethings on Audio & then PAss the Result to DB( Or Servlet )

My Question is that How to achieve such Applet-Servlet communication on Server Side.

It is Just similar to that of some Site which allows user to Upload Image & then They Process something (i.e. add Watermark, Resize extract detail etc) & then gives results. & I am trying same things ,but on Audio with the help of Applet & JSP-Servlet Which i have created.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You don't use an applet to do this. Sites that need post-processing do so in a *servlet*, without user interaction.

Comment: I decided Earlier dear but Actually The processing which I want, is not happening in servlet, on other hand it is smoothly working in Applet so I need to do so.Pls Help Me..

Comment: Are you really prepared to sit in front of a server console 24 hours a day 7 days a week, to interact with this applet?

Comment: If not, it might be really smart to look at the applet code and extract the pieces that do what you want, leaving the GUI pieces behind.

Comment: Ok I will But I am getting ""http-bio-8080"-exec-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Error in Servlet